# Solve $x^2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+\frac{dy}{dx}+x^2y=0$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the differential equation $$x^2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+\frac{dy}{dx}+x^2y=0$$

My try:

$$x^2 \frac{\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}}{y}=-x^2-\frac{\frac{dy}{dx}}{y}$$

RHS is a perfect differential, but LHS is not

any clue?

Comment: What are y, y_1, y_2? My guess: y a function from R to R, y_1 is its derivative, and y_2 is its second derivative.

Comment: Do you mean $y_2=y''$ etc ?

Comment: yes i edited accordingly

Comment: Why do you think this should have a closed form ?

Comment: What exactly is here understood under "solution"? A power series, asymptotic behaviour? Reduction to a Bessel or similar equation?

Comment: I would guess on some function with hidden internal derivative $x$ or $1/x$ or something similar, but I see other people have already done so.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Let $y=e^{ix}u$ ,

Then $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=e^{ix}\dfrac{du}{dx}+ie^{ix}u$

$\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}=e^{ix}\dfrac{d^2u}{dx^2}+ie^{ix}\dfrac{du}{dx}+ie^{ix}\dfrac{du}{dx}-e^{ix}u=e^{ix}\dfrac{d^2u}{dx^2}+2ie^{ix}\dfrac{du}{dx}-e^{ix}u$

$\therefore x^2\left(e^{ix}\dfrac{d^2u}{dx^2}+2ie^{ix}\dfrac{du}{dx}-e^{ix}u\right)+e^{ix}\dfrac{du}{dx}+ie^{ix}u+x^2e^{ix}u=0$

$x^2\left(\dfrac{d^2u}{dx^2}+2i\dfrac{du}{dx}-u\right)+\dfrac{du}{dx}+iu+x^2u=0$

$x^2\dfrac{d^2u}{dx^2}+(2ix^2+1)\dfrac{du}{dx}+iu=0$

Which relates to [Heun's Doubly-Confluent Equation](http://dlmf.nist.gov/31.12#E2).

Answer (score 0):

It is a Sturm Liouville equation, write
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(e^{-1/x}y'(x)\right)+e^{-1/x}y(x)=0$$

Comment: You are on right track, but some clarification could be good for the untrained student.